# Pass in buffer when library expects a file path node

Tags: node.js, file

I have a library that expects a filepath in order to load the data. However, I have the contents of the file in the form of a buffer instead. How do I make the buffer pretend to be a filepath?

Comment: have you got the solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

So you're saying you have a Buffer that's holding the route to a file. You want to convert the Buffer into a string. If that's what you're trying to do then, here you go:

```
var buff = new Buffer('/path/to/wonder/land.js');
buff.toString('utf8');
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I meant it contains the contents of the file.